# Structuring Ajax call for Redux-Form action to express with Mongo

Tags: ajax, mongodb, express, react-redux, redux-form

I am relatively new to JS and react and I'm using the Redux-Form to add a simple item into my mongo db. I have the form configured and the API is defined with db connection but I don't think I'm structuring my code in the action correctly such that it sends data in a way that can be interpreted.

Specifically I'm seeing the form data after pressing submit, but am getting 500 error. Can someone point me in the direction of shaping my ajax request appropriately so that this receives usable data for the db post?

[image]

new item form:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'; import { fetchItems } from '../actions/index'; import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form'; import { createItem } from '../actions/index';


class NewItem extends Component {

        render () {


            const { fields: {name, category, description, image}, handleSubmit } = this.props;


            return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.createItem)}>
                <h3>Add an Item</h3>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Item Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" {...name} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Category</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" {...category} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea className="form-control" {...description} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Image URL</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" {...image} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
            )
        }

}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'NewItemForm',
    fields: ['name', 'category', 'description', 'image'] }, null, {createItem})(NewItem);
```

action

```js
export const FETCH_MY_ITEMS = 'FETCH_MY_ITEMS';
export const FETCH_SEARCH_ITEMS = 'FETCH_SEARCH_ITEMS';
export const CREATE_ITEM = 'CREATE_ITEM';
export const FETCH_ITEM = 'FETCH_ITEM';
export const DELETE_ITEM = 'DELETE_ITEM';

export function createItem (props) {

     const request = $.post('/newItem', props).then(function (result){
    return {
        result
    }
});

    return {
        type: CREATE_ITEM,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

express index.js

```
app.post("/newItem", function(req, res) {
        var newItem = require('./server/api/new-item')(dbConnection);
        newItem(req, res);
    });
```

api endpoint for newItem

```
var assert = require('assert');

//add new item to 
module.exports = function (dbConnection) {
    return function (req, res) {

        var newItem = req.body.newItem;
        newItem.user = req.session.userId;
        newItem.createDate = new Date;
        dbConnection.collection('items').insertOne(newItem, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("error: something bad happened and your item was not saved")
            }
            res.send("success-item-posted");
            res.end();

        })
    }
};
```

Terminal Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined
    at /Users/mary/working-files/closet-redux/server/api/new-item.js:13:22
    at /Users/mary/working-files/closet-redux/index.js:184:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/mary/working-files/closet-redux/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/mary/working-files/closet-redux/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/mary/working-files/closet-redux/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/mary/working-files/closet-redux/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/mary/working-files/closet-redux/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/mary/working-files/closet-redux/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/mary/working-files/closet-redux/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at Immediate. (/Users/mary/working-files/closet-redux/node_modules/express-session/index.js:432:7)

Comment: in your action, what doe the console.log(result) return? there might be a valuable error message there. Also why not use `fetch` over $.post. They both generally work the same, but I find fetch works with promises well. I also wonder if adding `.catch(error)` would help catch an error as well. 

Let me know if any of this helps

Comment: I haven't done any of that because I'm a newbie and don't know about them :)  I had just added the console log - and adding terminal error to question.

Comment: Looks like I have an issue with user... I should have my logged in user in session with the userId stored... I'll look further into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bdougie, I looked carefully at my console log from the server and found 2 issues:

1) form was sending object, not named object so just needed to use req.body for my newItem variable

2) userId from session was giving error when added to newItem - and honestly I just moved it below the create date and tested with console.log and it's now working.